# The phrase "to get the run around"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, australian-english

Is "get the run around" a US idiom or is it widely understood throughout the English-speaking world?

I'm an American and recently I was in Argentina making a domestic flight connection from Buenos Aires to another Argentinian city.  My flight's gate-time was repeatedly delayed (we finally left 6 hours late) and when I asked gate attendants and other airline staff what the problem was and when the plane would arrive at the gate I either got conflicting answers, or was referred to other staff who kept referring me to others, etc, with no useful information.  I sometimes got the sense they knew more than they were saying. I could see on the departure/arrivals board that many flights were affected.  (the next day I found out in the news that there had been a short air traffic controllers' strike).

In the US we call the experience I had with the airline staff "getting the run around".  I'm writing an email to an Australian friend in which I want to describe my experience and **my question is**, is "getting the run around" an idiom that is understood throughout the English-speaking world or is it unique to America?    Is there another widely-used expression that might substitute?    Is there an Australian slang or idiomatic phrase that expresses my experience?

Comment: I try to avoid *getting* the runaround by telling people right up front: *Don't **give** me the runaround!*

Comment: I've always known it (in GB), and I can easily imagine hearing it in an Aussie accent, so I'd say it's probably well-known everywhere. Besides which, the meaning would be pretty transparent in any normal context even if you *hadn't* heard it before. And it's obviously [taken off in written BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+runaround&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20runaround%3B%2Cc0) since the early 60s. Certainly easier to throw in than something like *I got passed from pillar to post*.

Comment: Remember those old silent movies where the guy runs in a room then out another room and then the cops come after him from another (or the re-enactment of such in cartoons like Loony Toons and Scooby Doo).  I think anywhere people watched any of those "the run around" will be understood.

Comment: Yes it's popular idiom over here in the UK.

Comment: I think it works in any dialect, and I also think *run-around* should be hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, an Australian English speaker like me will know precisely what you mean.

The more common formulation in Australia is probably "giving" rather than "getting" (as in, *"The airline company is giving me the run around"*) but the "getting" formulation is used too.

For example, this post on a common Australian consumer forum is complaining about an Aussie telephone company giving someone ["the run around"](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/876094) and the site has other posts that use that expression too.

Note that we are all using "run around" in two words but as a single noun it probably should be hyphenated or used as a single word "runaround", as the following entries put it.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=runaround)  has this entry that suggests a 1915 origin for the use of "runaround" as a noun in this way, although does not mention where in the English-speaking world it first arose:

> runaround (n.)
>   also run-around, "deceptive, evasive treatment," 1915, from verbal phrase, from run (v.) + around (adv.).

The Collins Dictionary online puts it in both British and American English and notice the usage graph suggesting a slightly later origin for [runaround](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/runaround).

Finally, you ask if there are any Australian expressions you might substitute. I can't think of one - the phrase is just perfect as it is mate!